# Don't know which boundary cases for ABSURD on SPOJ are giving wrong answer

Tags: java

Here's the complete code,

```
  package spoj;
  import java.util.*;
  import java.util.regex.*;
  import java.text.*;
  import java.math.*;
  import java.awt.geom.*;
  import java.io.*;


  public class ABSURD {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String in = sc.nextLine();
    long t = Long.parseLong(in);
    while(t>0)
    {
        String n;
        n = sc.nextLine();

        int i= n.length()-1;
        while(i>=0)
        {
            if(n.charAt(i) != '0')
                break;
            i--;
        }
        long k = Long.parseLong(n);
        double x1 = (.95 * (double)k);
        double x2 = (1.05*(double)k);
        long x = (long)x1;
        long y = (long)x2;
        if((double)x == x1)
            x = x-1;
       System.out.println(x+" "+y);
        n = n.substring(0,i+1);
       // System.out.println(n);
        if(n.equals(""))
        {
            System.out.println("not absurd");
            t--;
            continue;

        }


        String a = Long.toString(x);
        int la = a.length();
        String b = Long.toString(y);
        int lb = b.length();

        int absurdity  = n.charAt(n.length()-1) == 5?2*n.length()-1:2*n.length();
        //System.out.println(absurdity);
        String answer = "not absurd";
        if(n.length() == 1)
        {

                answer = "not absurd";
        }
        else
        {
            if(la<lb)
            {
                if(absurdity >2)
                    answer = "absurd";
            }

            if(lb == la)
            {
                int j=0;
                while(j<la)
                {
                    if(a.charAt(j) != b.charAt(j))
                        break;
                    j++;

                }
            int absurd = a.charAt(j)<'5' && b.charAt(j)>='5'?2*(j+1)-1:2*(j+1);
            //System.out.println(absurd);
            if(absurd<absurdity)
                answer = "absurd";

            }

        }


        System.out.println(answer);

        t--;

    }
    }

  }
```

The problem is ABSURD. Link to the problem is: http://www.spoj.com/problems/ABSURD/. I don't know for which test case it fails, have tried a lot of them. Basically one has to cut down the trailing zeroes and calculate absurdity according to the given rule. And then one has to determine if an integer exist in the given range having absurdity less than the absurdity of given number.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few potential bugs in your code. I won't discuss them here but will let you figure out yourself (well, that's the whole point of the exercise). However, I'll give a few cases where your code emits incorrect result. I hope this will enable you to proceed further.

1. 15 (Output should be *not absurd*, you output *absurd*)
2. 25 (Output should be *not absurd*, you output *absurd*)
3. 55 (Output should be *not absurd*, you output *absurd*)
4. 1500 (Output should be *not absurd*, you output *absurd*)